# Autocorrect to closest possible value (quantity form WordPress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am building a webshop with WooCommerce.
We are using WooCommerce advanced quantity so the quantity is not like 1,2,3,4 etc but in steps of 0.72 for example. When using the +/- button it is working fine. (steps: 0.72, 1.44, 2.16 etc)

When I fill in 20 with my keyboard and click add to my cart in my cart there has been add a quantity of 19.44 instead of 20 because 20 is not an possible option. I want the field to autocorrect to the closest possible quantity value before adding it to my cart. So more like autocorrect it after deselecting the field.

How can I achieve this? Has it something to do with javascript?
Hope you guys can help me!

Link to example page so you can test it: https://www.stenenentegels.nl/product/trommelsteen-chelsea-20x30x4/

Comment: I'm absolutely sure it has nothing to do with PHP at least. Unless you want to do it at checkout or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set the value to the current value minus itself with the modulus operator. You can determine the best event, but `blur` would probably work best.

```js
let qty = document.getElementById('qty');

qty.onblur = function(){
  let val  = this.value; // Current Value
  let step = this.getAttribute('step'); // Get step instead of hard coding it
  
  this.value = (val - (val % step)).toFixed(2); // Simple math that adjusts the value on blur
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="qty" step=".72" />
```

To round up one step, you could consider:

```js
let qty = document.getElementById('qty');

qty.onblur = function(){
  let val  = this.value; // Current Value
  let step = this.getAttribute('step'); // Get step instead of hard coding it
  
  let roundDown = (val - (val % step)).toFixed(2);
  let roundUp   = (parseFloat(roundDown) + parseFloat(step)).toFixed(2);
  
  this.value = roundUp;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="qty" step=".72" />
```

If you only want this to effect steps that aren't `1`, just wrap that in an if statement:

```js
let qty = document.getElementById('qty');

qty.onblur = function(){
  let val  = this.value; // Current Value
  let step = this.getAttribute('step'); // Get step instead of hard coding it
  
  if( step != 1 ){
    let roundDown = (val - (val % step)).toFixed(2);
    let roundUp   = (parseFloat(roundDown) + parseFloat(step)).toFixed(2);
  
    this.value = roundUp;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="qty" step=".72" />
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me on this page: https://www.stenenentegels.nl/product/trommelsteen-chelsea-20x30x4-kopie/

but when I add it to my cart it needs to pass that value to the carts quantity field because that one is empty now. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Looks like the values may be set incorrectly in your Advanced Quantities? The field value shows in the code (but not in the field because it's a number field, not a text field), but it the value is showing in Inspect Element as `3 × €36,00per m²`

Comment: Okay i will take a look at it. Last question for now:
For example when I fill 11 in the field it rounds down to 10.8 because it is the closest possible option. But I want it to always round UP to the clost possible option

Comment: I've updated the function, basically you can just add another `+ step` before rounding it: `this.value = (val + step - (val % step)).toFixed(2);`

Comment: When i update the function and fill in 11 it rounds up to 110.52

Comment: D'oh, my apologies. I hit Run Snippet instead of save, I've updated it now for real

Comment: Oh do you mean in your own site, hold on

Comment: I exactly copied your code but still gets 110.52 instead of 11.52. See this page: https://www.stenenentegels.nl/product/trommelsteen-chelsea-20x30x4-kopie/

Comment: Hmm, nothing seems too out of the ordinary. I've updated the code again, perhaps you need to parse the integer values

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work either. What was the first code you had? For now that was the one which worked best for me.

Comment: I've replaced the code with the original version. Also I made a booboo earlier and was using `parseInt` instead of `parseFloat`. I added another function that would allow you to replace the variable with `roundDown` or `roundUp` at your leisure - you could see if that works better. I think it may have been a concatenation problem earlier

Comment: I uploaded the new function with the roundUp in it. The function works nice with taking the closest possible option but still rounds it down :(

Comment: Hi man, everything is working fine now but I see one problem now. I have two examples: 

https://www.stenenentegels.nl/product/trommelsteen-chelsea-20x30x4/

and

https://www.stenenentegels.nl/product/betonband-antraciet-100x20x10/

The second link works with steps of 1 each time and doesn't need the javascript for rounding it up. I only want to use the script when I work with differrent steps than 1. Is there an option to modify the script?

Comment: There sure is, I added another snippet, just wrap the modifier with an `if ( step != 1) ` so it will only apply if the step isn't `1` (or even `1.00`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks! Works great!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in the blur event of the #qty field with javascript:

```
jQuery("#qty").on("blur", function(){
    correctValue = jQuery(this).val() - (jQuery(this).val() % 0.72);   
    jQuery(this).val(correctValue.toFixed(2));
})
```

Edit: You need to find a place to put this - in a WooCommerce template or in the general js file of the site.

Edit 2: You can check that this actually works by pasting the above code in the Chrome JS console and then entering "20" in the field and clicking out of the field again.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me on this page: stenenentegels.nl/product/trommelsteen-chelsea-20x30x4-kopie 

but when I add it to my cart it needs to pass that value to the carts quantity field because that one is empty now. How can I achieve that?